# java simple console game "ships" cant add a "ship" to an array, im completely stucked

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, console

iam making a simple game called ships, i made a 2D array (10x10), i have a problem with adding a "ship" to array ( the point of the game is to find a ship in an array), im completely stucked so i am looking for a help, sorry for mistakes and etc, but this is my first post and i am just begginer. Thanks!

Here is MAIN

```
public class Play
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
      {
            Grid grid = new Grid(10);
            grid.fillArr('o');
            grid.printArr();
            Objects ships = new Object(0);
            ship.getShip('X');

      }
}
```

Object(SHIP) CLASS

```
public class Objects
{
    //FIELDS
    private int ship;

    //CONSTRUCTORS
    public Objects(int ship)
    {
        this.ship = ship;
    }

    //METHODS
    public int getShip()
    {
        return ship;
    }

    public void getLod(char c) 
    {

    } 
}
```

Here is the Grid Class

```
public class Grid
{
    //FIELDS
    char[][] arr;
    private Objects[] ship;
    private int numofShips; 

    //CONSTRUCTORS
    public Grid(int a) 
    {
        arr = new char [a][a]; 
        ship = new Objects[10];
    }

    //METHODS
    public void printArr()
    {

        for(int q = 0; q < arr.length; q = q + 1)
        {
            for(int w = 0; w < arr.length; w++)
            {
                System.out.print(arr[q][w] + " ");
            }
                System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public void fillArr(char c)
    {

        for(int q = 0; q < arr.length; q++)
        {
            for(int w = 0; w < arr.length; w++)
            {
                arr[q][w] = c;
            }
        }
    }

    public void reloadGrid()
      {
        //Draw base grid
        for(int r = 0; r < arr.length; r++)
          for(int c = 0; c < arr[r].length; c++)
            arr[r][c] = 'o';

        //Draw ship  <-----THIS IS A PROBLEM...//////////////////////////////
        for(int i = 0; i < numofShips; i++)
        {

        }
      }
      public void addToGrid(Objects p)
      {
        ship[numofShips] = p;
        numofShips++;
      }
}
```

Sorry for all mistakes in the code.

Comment: You should at least try to find a solution by yourself. When you have it, if it does not work, maybe we can help you.

Comment: How can this even work? Objects ships = new Object(0);

Comment: Speaking of which, what is the use of the class "objects"?

Comment: it should most probably be `Objects ships = new Objects(0);`

Comment: You should consider renaming you class `Objects`. If it represent a ship, just call it Ship. Then in your main, you have the mistake seen in other comments and you are calling ship.getShip(int) but it isn't declared

Comment: Are you doing the battleship assignment?

Comment: Where/how is your code failing? What is the error, or rather, what is/isn't happening that should(n't)?

Comment: You should rename `Objects` to `Ship`, so you don't confuse your class with the built-in Java class, `Object`, which every other Java class extends. And looking at the 4th line of your `main()` method, that's exactly what you've done.